# "Expected Value" of a solution to a differential equation

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm going to write this question in a very informal way as I'm looking for guidance, rather than a specific answer to a specific problem. So I took a course on stochastic processes and Martingales recently. My current study interest is to try and understand the (possibly many) relations between stochastic processes and IVPs. I am investigating the following question:

> *How can stochastic processes provide information on behavior of solutions to differential equations?*

#### What Motivated the Question:

So I am given a function $u:\Omega\times[0,T]\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying the IVP: $$ \begin{cases}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}=F(u,D^\alpha u),\\ u(x,0)=u_0(x).\end{cases}$$
As we all know, a lot of the times these equations are very difficult to solve explicitly and even more difficult to understand their behavior (say in the $L^\infty$ sense for example). Of course, a lucky case is when the solution satisfies some known modulus principle. But this is far from a general case. So I want to ask myself a supposedly simpler questions:

> *What is the expected behavior of a solution, given the initial data $u_0$?*

So after a bit of thought I asked myself: What if one can construct a stochastic process $\{X_t\}$ such that $X_0$ "holds" the initial data $u_0$ and then $X_t$ "predicts" the behavior of $u(t)$ using the above equation? By predict, I mean where do I expect my $u(x,t)$ to be given that $u_0(x)$ for some $t$ "close enough" to 0. Such a process would of course be constructed using the function $F$ and imposed properties on the solution. In the language of stochastic processes, I want to make explicit the following:
$$'E[u(t)\mid u_0]': \text{The expected value of $u$ at time $t$ given $u_0$}.$$

Very informally, I'm using the symbol $E[u(t)\mid u_0]\sim E[u(t)\mid\sigma(u_0)]$ where $\sigma(u_0)$ is the "information" I get from $u_0$ (not necessarily the $\sigma$-algebra of $u_0$).

Also, is it possible to find a stochastic process $\{X_t\}$ and an outcome $\omega$ such that $X_t(\omega)\sim u(t)$?

I hope I am making sense here. Do you think it is a good question? If there is any remark let me know in the comments so that I can edit. Some guidance would be of great help!
Thank you in advance.

---

So in the comments, I found out that something like [Feynman-Kac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula) is one answer to my question. But Feynman-Kac gives an explicit solution. What I am looking for is more of "behaviour analysis" of solutions to PDEs using stochastic processes.

Comment: In some sense, that is what the field of dynamical systems is all about. Especially Ergodic theory. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_theory

Comment: sounds like [feynman-kac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman–Kac_formula) I think

Comment: Is something like [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.1863.pdf) the type of thing you are thinking of? A probabilistic method of computing solutions for PDEs, which gets the right answer on average?

Comment: This is not my field of expertise, therefore I decided to post a comment instead of an answer. My advice is to have a look at the book of Mark I. Freidlin, _Functional integration and partial differential equations_, Annals of Mathematics Studies, No. 109, Princeton University Press. In this monograph the Feynman-Kac formula is used jointly with a perturbation method to study the properties (time asymptotic and other) of several kinds of PDEs, including quasi linear equations of KPP type.